# New-added Maven plugin becomes red in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, maven-central

I'm following this [guideline](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html) for a Maven plugin, after which I've added the following:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
</plugin>
```

`maven-release-plugin` & `2.5.3` are both red. I'm using a local Maven repository. How can I update it? Do I need to install anything so that *IntelliJ* can find it? I'm new to Maven and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Can't reproduce, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least the complete `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the following in Maven pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Once added , wait for 2 mins in Intellij Idea based upon the network speed.
Still does not work, click on the right side of Intellij Idea having a tab "Maven" and click refresh button. See the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your IntelliJ maven configuration at `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Maven`

1. Work Offline is not checked
2. Your local repository is correct

[image]

Double-check your local repository folder usually at `%HOMEPATH%\.m2\repository\` and go through the subfolders `org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-release-plugin` if you do not find a jar file the dependency was not downloaded.

You can try to force maven to download the missing dependencies. Navigate to your project `pom.xml` file and run the following command:

```
mvn -U -X dependency:copy-dependencies
```

The `-U` force the update and `-X` produce a debug log with more information about what is going wrong.

If you have a file `%HOMEPATH%\.m2\setting.xml` check the content and see if there is any proxy information. You can try to rename this file and force the update again.

You can also install [dependency manually](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) Download the jar and try the command:

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-release-plugin -Dversion=2.5.3
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed answer, this could be another solution (potentially), but I'll give the best answer to Debadatta since I solved my problem by using his (her) solution. Thanks for your effort again, I really appreciated it.